# Knockout.js Bindinghandlers Bootstrap.DatePicker

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, knockout.js, datepicker, bindinghandlers

I'm using Twitter Bootstrap.DatePicker with knockout. The problem that I'm having is that I can't get it to work properly. It's working fine when there is an initial date, but when there is no initial date I am getting the following error: **Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'getTime' of undefined**

**HTML**

```
<div id='target'>
    <input data-bind='datepicker: test_date'/>

    <div data-bind="text: test_date"></div>

    <input data-bind='datepicker: test_date_empty'/>
</div>
```

**BindingHandler**

```
ko.bindingHandlers.datepicker = {
    init: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor) {
      //initialize datepicker with some optional options
      var options = allBindingsAccessor().datepickerOptions || {};
      $(element).datepicker(options);

      //when a user changes the date, update the view model
      ko.utils.registerEventHandler(element, "changeDate", function(event) {
             var value = valueAccessor();
             if (ko.isObservable(value)) {
                 value(event.date);
             }                
      });
    },
    update: function(element, valueAccessor)   {
        var widget = $(element).data("datepicker");
         //when the view model is updated, update the widget
        if (widget) {
            widget.date = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor());

            if (!widget.date) {
                return;
            }                

            if (_.isString(widget.date)) {
                widget.date = new Date(widget.date);
            }

            widget.setValue();
        }
    }
};

var model = {
    test_date: ko.observable(),
    test_date_empty: ko.observable()
};


ko.applyBindings(model, $("#target")[0]);

model.test_date("2012/04/04")
model.test_date_empty()
```

I have created a JSFiddle where the behaviour is demonstrated http://jsfiddle.net/DirkMolman/ACKyp/5/

I's using knockout 2.3.0 and Bootstrap.datepicker 1.1.3.1

I hope that someone can help me solve this problem.

Answer (score 2):

I don't have much experience with the Bootstrap DatePicker before, but it looks like you could use the `setDate` API and if the value is empty, then force a `change` event on the element with an empty value. Based on your current code, in your `update` it would look something like:

```
    if (widget) {
        value = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor());

        if (!value) { 
           $(element).val("").change();
           return;
        }

        widget.setDate(_.isString(value) ? new Date(value) : value);
    }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/JRCsb/